# How to use tail -f in a shell script?

Tags: bash, shell

I am writing a shell script that is supposed to monitor some log files and redirect the output to a file. I am using `tail -f` command to do so, but it doesnt seem to work. Here is my script.

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh -q sc-2 tail -f /home/logs/oam-2.log > /root/logs/file.log &

echo "press return to strop the trace"

read A

kill `ps -ef| grep tail| grep sc-2| grep "\.log"| awk '{print $2}'` 2>/dev/null &
```

When I run the script, only 5 lines are printed in the file.log

Comment: Why do this? Won't the data already be in the log file?

Comment: It might be related to `ssh`. Can you reproduce the issue directly on `sc-2`?

Comment: sc-2 is the hostname. it is so weird, because when i use tail -f in the command prompt it works perfectly, but then when i use it in my script it only displays 5 lines

Comment: Your `kill` is more complex than it needs to be. `ssh ... & ssh_pid=$!`, followed later by `kill $ssh_pid`.

Comment: Could it be a buffering issue?

Comment: Have you run the `ssh` line directly from a command prompt rather than a script, including the background processing (`&`)? I'd like to know how it behaves. I cobbled up an example and it would just say that the `ssh` process "Stopped" almost immediately and it would create an empty `file.log`. But the `ssh` process would show as running in `ps ax`. Weird. Run directly, not as an `ssh` it ran as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you are sending the `ssh` process to the background via `&`, its file descriptors are still "attached" to your terminal. A demonstration:

```
# Terminal 1
$ ssh $host sleep 600 &
[3] 14340

# Terminal 2
$ ls -l /proc/14340/fd
lrwx------ 1 iscfrc iscfrc 64 Oct  3 10:30 0 -> /dev/pts/1
lrwx------ 1 iscfrc iscfrc 64 Oct  3 10:30 1 -> /dev/pts/1
lrwx------ 1 iscfrc iscfrc 64 Oct  3 10:30 2 -> /dev/pts/1
lr-x------ 1 iscfrc iscfrc 64 Oct  3 10:30 3 -> socket:[125941180]
lrwx------ 1 iscfrc iscfrc 64 Oct  3 10:31 4 -> /dev/pts/1
lrwx------ 1 iscfrc iscfrc 64 Oct  3 10:31 5 -> /dev/pts/1
lrwx------ 1 iscfrc iscfrc 64 Oct  3 10:31 6 -> /dev/pts/1
```

Note how all the FDs (Minus the TCP socket) are attached to `/dev/pts/1`.

So what happens when your script runs `ssh`, puts it in to the background, but the `ssh` process continues to poll the terminal for input?

```
# Terminal 2
$ sudo strace -p 14340
Process 14340 attached - interrupt to quit
select(7, [3 4], [], NULL, NULL

# Terminal 1
$ read

# Terminal 2, output
select(7, [3 4], [], NULL, NULL)        = 1 (in [4])
read(4, 0xbff1dbbc, 16384)              = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted)
--- SIGTTIN (Stopped (tty input)) @ 0 (0) ---
--- SIGTTIN (Stopped (tty input)) @ 0 (0) ---
# (infinite loop of the previous three lines)
```

It goes in to panic when attempting to `read()` input from file descriptor `4`, which you can see above is the terminal. (`4 -> /dev/pts/1`)

The solution is to disconnect `ssh` from the terminal's input; I recommend using `nohup`:

```
nohup ssh -q sc-2 tail -f /home/logs/oam-2.log > /root/logs/file.log &
```

Additional suggestions for consideration:

1. Add the `-T` argument to your `ssh` command to disable TTY allocation on the remote host. Since you don't need to interact with the `tail` command a TTY is unnecessary.
2. Store the PID of the `ssh` command in to a variable via `$!` in order to save yourself needing to parse the output of `ps`.
3. And to be even more spartan, you can save yourself an `echo` by using `read`'s `-p` option. (`p` is for *prompt*)

Combining all of the above:

```
nohup ssh -qT sc-2 tail -f /home/logs/oam-2.log >/root/logs/file.log &
sshpid=$!
read -p $'press return to stop the trace\n'
kill $sshpid
```

I tested the above (With my own host/files paths filled in) and it ran for >10 minutes without stopping.

Comment: this solution is very close to what i want, however this script is only responsible to start the tail command and put the output in the log file. I need to write another function called print_stop where it will kill the command when the invoked

Comment: the only concern i have is even with nohup tail is still not running in the background.

Comment: You used both the terms script and function - are you saying that you need to write two scripts, one to start the `ssh` process and another to kill it later? If so, you'll need to use `nohup` to start that script instead of using it inside the script itself. If that's not the case, I'm not sure why it wouldn't be going in to the background - as long as the `&` is at the end of the `nohup` line it should.

Comment: sorry for the confusion. I am writing one script that contains several function, the lines of code i posted are part of the print_start function, i have a function print_stop that is responsible to stop tail -f from running. this is my line:nohup ssh -f -qT sc-2 tail -f /home/logs/oam-2.log > /root/logs/file.log 2>/dev/null &.

Comment: It would probably be best if you replaced the example in your question with the entirety of the script, or at least a close facsimile; it's going to be tough to come up with an answer without being able to see the entire picture.

Comment: i think i found the main problem. It is ssh. When i run this command : nohup ssh -qT sc-2 tail -f /home/logs/oam-2.log > /root/logs/file.log 2>/dev/null &. No output is written to the file.log when i tail without ssh, it works perfectly. do you have any idea why.